# Why is the wrong element is being selected when trying to click a button with Puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web-scraping, google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer

I am trying to create an automate login through puppeteer that logs me into yahoo and auto forwards my yahoo accounts all to one domain name.

I am having a very annoying problem though where when I try to click the `Next` button via the command `await page.click('[type=submit]');`  instead the an add seems to be selected instead.

I did some web scraping via dev tools and the type to the button is submit. Is there some way I can better specify what button to click to via this problem?

The [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vESse.jpg) shows the screen that I am on when trying to login, when the the submit button is pressed I am brought to the nord security add

To better explain, the nord security add is selected opening a new tab not doing as intended. Any help is much appreciated!!

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');


async function main() {
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.setViewport({width: 800, height: 500})
await page.goto('https://login.yahoo.com');


await page.type('[name=username]', 'YAHOO ACCOUNT LISTED HERE');
await this.page.waitFor(2000);
await page.click('[type=submit]');
// click and wait for navigation

}

main();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Problem is JavaScript Context,**

To understand this

- go to https://login.yahoo.com in chrome
- open dev tools change java script context (highlighted in image) to about blank
- then fire query $("[type='submit']") // will return null
- then change java script context to top then fire query again$([type='submit']") // will return element
  [image]

**Solution:**

you can reach out to the iframe you want with page.frames() method. After you find the iframe you want, you can use frame.evaluate to evaluate inside frame's context.

// find the iframe we care about

// cost iframe = page.frames().find(iframe => iframe.url().includes('localhost'));

// evaluate inside a particular iframe

//await iframe.evaluate(() => console.log('Look! I am inside iframe!'));

Comment: I looked into this but I am still having trouble finding a solution in which Iframe is able to fix. Most likely due to my low understanding of Iframes but thanks for this help.